# use iis 8 to remove a section of a URL whilst keeping all other sections

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

The input url is `http://www.mywebsite.com/en-us/lookingtobuy/propertiesforsale.aspx?ppid=MD19863` and I need the URL to redirst to `http://www.mywebsite.com/lookingtobuy/propertiesforsale.aspx?ppid=MD19863`

So I need to remove the `en-us/`

everything following the `?ppid/` is a variable and so any rule written would need to allow for that to match what ever the input is

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work :

```
<rule name="remove en-US">
  <match url="^/en-US/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite"
          url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And if you need to allow other culture

```
<rule name="remove culture">
  <match url="^/(\w{2}-\w{2})/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite"
          url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

`{R:x}` is a back reference to the rule pattern. For the second rule

- `{R:0}` will be `/en-us/lookingtobuy/propertiesforsale.aspx?ppid=MD19863`
- `{R:1}` will be `en-us`
- `{R:2}` will be `lookingtobuy/propertiesforsale.aspx?ppid=MD19863`